# The RAID 1 Time machine

Tags: linux, raid, lvm

Last night my server crashed, after reboot I have found it has a disk failure

The configuration is 2 x 500GB sata on Centos 6

- sda3/sdb3 is software RAID1
- sda1/sdb1 = ext3 for /
- sda2/sdb2 = swap
- sda3/sdb3 = LVM
- LVM = /var, /usr, /home, /opt, /backup

disk sdb has failed, it is currently running only on sda

Now for the magic...

after rebooting, the entire filesystem has gone back a year and a half?

today is 14/07/15, the last file updated is 15/02/14

So my question is, how can a LVM on top of RAID1 go back in time???

no backups, well at least not in date anymore :( they were all on the LVM /backup partition which has also gone back in time

Many thanks

Stuart

Comment: A wild guess is that the RAID sda/sdb3 had failed a long time ago, running only on sdb. Now that sdb has failed, perhaps it came back online with only sda?

Comment: +1 for that guess. Same thing happened to a friend's server some time ago...

Comment: That's not a wild guess, that's the correct answer most likely. Time to test if at least your backup was working (or to ship the disks to a recovery firm).

Comment: Halfgaar, can you add that as answer so I can mark as correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, now as an answer:

A wild guess is that the RAID sda/sdb3 had failed a long time ago, running only on sdb. Now that sdb has failed, perhaps it came back online with only sda?